# XSL Templates for XML Documentation in MonoDevelop

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop, xml-documentation

I am using MonoDevelop with the Unity 3D engine and have created a class library. I have added XML document comments above each function, etc.

Generating the XML data file was quite easy, but are there any default XSLT templates that I can use? I have seen the name "MonoDoc" dotted around, but there doesn't appear to be anything like that included with MonoDevelop nor can I find a download.

What is the quickest way to generate HTML files from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated XML files can be compiled using SandCastle (http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/).

I found it easier to use the SandCastyle Help File Builder (SHFB) tool (http://shfb.codeplex.com/).